# Object reference not set to an instance of an object when using wsdl tool

Tags: web-services, mono, wsdl

I'm trying to get class from this wsdl

http://e-pelmex.com.br/services/soap?wsdl

But i get this error

```
nati pelmex # wsdl  http://e-pelmex.com.br/services/soap?wsdl
    Web Services Description Language Utility
    Mono Framework v4.0.30319.17020
    Error: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
    Stack:
       at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializationReader.OnUnknownNode (System.Xml.XmlNode node, System.Object o, System.String qnames) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
      at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializationReader.UnknownNode (System.Object o, System.String qnames) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
      at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializationReader.UnknownNode (System.Object o) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
      at System.Web.Services.Description.ServiceDescriptionReaderBase.ReadObject_ServiceDescription (Boolean isNullable, Boolean checkType) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
      at System.Web.Services.Description.ServiceDescriptionReaderBase.ReadRoot_ServiceDescription () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
      at System.Web.Services.Description.ServiceDescription+ServiceDescriptionSerializer.Deserialize (System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializationReader reader) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
      at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Deserialize (System.Xml.XmlReader xmlReader) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
      at System.Web.Services.Description.ServiceDescription.Read (System.Xml.XmlReader reader) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
      at System.Web.Services.Discovery.DiscoveryClientProtocol.DiscoverAny (System.String url) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
      at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.Web.Services.Discovery.DiscoveryClientProtocol:DiscoverAny (string)
      at Mono.WebServices.Driver.Run (System.String[] args) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
    nati pelmex #
```

Any idea?

Comment: Does Mono not have the svcutil tool? You're using legacy technology that shouldn't be used for new development (at least, not in general).

Comment: what version of mono are you using Bruno?

Comment: John, can you elaborate on why do you think Bruno is using legacy tech?

Comment: Yeh! why legacy? :P i'm new in this language. Knocte, I'm using mono compiler 3.0.6. I think was problem with WSDL structure. I'll try with some simple soap server